# Write integral in different order

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I rewrite, the following triple integrals into different orders?:
$$\int^1_0\int^{z^2}_0\int^y_0{f} \, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$$
In the orders $\mathrm{d}z \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y$ and $\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Currently the limits are:
$$\begin{split}
&0 \le x \le y \\
&0 \le y \le z^2 \\
&0 \le z \le 1
\end{split}$$

Comment: Have you tried [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)?

Comment: @user251257 No, can you show me that in this case please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your $f$ satisfies the assumption of Fubini's theorem.

Let $S = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3 \mid 0 \le x \le y \le z^2, 0\le z \le 1 \}$.
It follows
\begin{align} 
\int_S f(x,y,z) \;\mathrm d(x,y,z)
&= \int_0^1 \int_{S_y} f(x,y,z) \;\mathrm d(x,z) \mathrm dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \int_{S_{(x,y)}} f(x,y,z) \;\mathrm dz \mathrm dx\mathrm dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \int_{\sqrt y}^1 f(x,y,z) \;\mathrm dz \mathrm dx\mathrm dy, 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
S_y &= \{ (x,z)\in\mathbb R^2 \mid (x,y,z) \in S \}, \\
S_{(x,y)} &= \{ z\in\mathbb R \mid (x,y,z) \in S \}.
\end{align}

The second one is analogue.